# Array that can only contain the given types in MSON

Tags: mson, aglio

How do I specify in MSON that an array should **only** contain types A, B or C, and not any other types?

I've tried

```
+ myField (array[A], fixed-type, required)
```

but the JSON schema generated by aglio only requires the first element of the array to be of type A.

Comment: Keep in mind Aglio is using an outdated version of the parser which might probably contain bugs. You might want to try it on Apiary.io first.

Answer (score 0):

The `fixed-type` feature of MSON is relatively new. If you've had Aglio installed for a while, you are probably using an older version of the parser. You can uninstall/reinstall it and see if it'll pick up the latest version of the `protagonist` library (which includes the feature), or you can install from Github which supports the new `drafter` library and should see a release soon. One of the big benefits there is that it no longer requires a compiler to install.